# What is Explicit Project in TFS Reports?

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, tfs-2015

I have been trying to generate reports using the Default Reports(Bug Status) in TFS but I don't know what value to give for Explicit Project?

Can anyone help me regarding this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That parameter is supposed to be hidden and automatically populated by the Report Server based on the folder the report is stored in. You seem to have a modified version of the report or your report server is not setup correctly to set the project automatically.

Comment: How to do that? My Reports reside under TFSReports/Project/Report.rdl

whereas my project in TFS is http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Project

Comment: When entering it manually just the project name should do. But I suspect the reports are from an older version and haven't been overwritten after the upgrade.

Comment: You were right..When I opened Reports from Visual Studio the url was different from the one I used for accessing Project (It had an extra folder something like TFSReports/Something/Project ..After Re-creating the same url path it worked like a Charm)